# Another word for "opportunities"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

As in "job opportunities"

I found some synonyms, but they just don't fit:

> "openings, chances, possibilities, etc."

Inserting one of those words in a sentence like this doesn't work, that is, without changing the meaning.

> A college degree can get you more job opportunities.

I'm writing something where I have to use that phrase quite a bit. I don't want it to sound redundant.

Comment: @sumelic Because I'm writing something where I have to use that phrase quite a bit.  I don't want it to sound redundant.

Comment: If you give us the entire phrase in which you wish *"opportunities"* to be replaced, we can help you easier than without a proper context.

Comment: Prospects perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some alternatives:

1. A college degree has more scope.
2. A college degree enables higher job potential.
3. A college degree provides more job openings.
4. A college degree enables job flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

"prospects" is a good replacement. Is is close in meaning to "possibilities".

> A college degree can open you to new (job) prospects.

[Oxford English Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/prospect) definition:

> Chances or opportunities for success or wealth: 
> *'the poor
>   prospects for the steel industry'*

Answer (score 0):

The following should also work as alternatives:

> A college degree can get you a better choice (of jobs).
>
> A college degree can get you more (career) choices.

From [**oxforddictionaries.com**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/choice):

> ***choice*** 
>   *NOUN*
>
> **1.2** A range of possibilities from which one or more may be chosen: *you can have a sofa made in a **choice** of forty fabrics*
>
> The Boeing business jet also comes with a choice of interior
>   decoration ranging from the basic to sumptuous.
>
> The choice of bar can
>   range from a close-knit pub setting to a party animal's dream.
>
> Walkers
>   set off from Cudham village on a choice of routes ranging from three
>   to eight miles.
>
> **Synonyms**: range, variety, selection,
>   assortment; array, display
>
> **1.3** A thing or person which is chosen: this disk drive is the perfect choice for your computer
>
> Garry was an ideal
>   choice to present the prize on behalf of the slimming group because he
>   lost two stones through their plan earlier this year.
>
> Particularly,
>   chopsticks are also a good choice when people send presents to
>   relatives and friends.
>
> The flight prize was an easy choice for the
>   leading lawman with a long-standing interest in aviation.
>
> **Synonyms**: appointee; nominee, candidate, selection